# Not able to login with linkedIn after uploading to play store, (Working in release apk directly but not from play store)

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I have created release apk and try to login with LinkedIn and it worked fine but when I uploaded it to play store and try login with LinkedIn. it failed with errorMessage: "either bundle id or package name / hash are invalid, unknown, malformed"

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow below mentioned steps.

- Open **play store console** -> goto **Release management** -> **App Signing** and copy **SHA-1** key like below
  [image]
- Open [this URL](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en) and past your copied SHA-1 key then you will get new `Hash key` in `Output (base64):`
- After that you have to put new key into your `LinkedIn account`.
  [image]